# Why does the order of the data change depending on the instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm readings Hamacher's Computer Organization and Embedded Design, just getting started with mips. On page 7, there are a few examples of assembly lines:

```
Load R2, LOC
Add R4, R2, R3
Store R4, LOC
```

In the first one, the content of LOC is read and loaded into register R2.
In the second line, the contents of registers R3 and R2 are added and the result is stored in R4. So far it follows a pattern. First comes the register where the data will be stored, then one or more addresses/registers that the data will be read from.

But then in the third line, according to the book, the content of R4 is copied from that register onto the address LOC. Suddenly it doesn't follow the pattern. Why? Why not `Store LOC, R4` ? Is it that the first parameter can't be a memory address ever? So I just have to change the order whenever the "receiving" location is a memory address instead of a register?

Comment: to make the parsers job easier?

Comment: The first MIPS assemblers were probably created by University professors. One day they asked a student to code the Store instruction parsing. No one noticed it was backwards until their assemblers were out the door. To this day it remain reversed. PS: Don't believe everything you read on the Internet ;)

Comment: Not only in the assembler but also in the opcode there is the inversion.

Comment: @dwelch can you elaborate? Why does this make the parser's job easier?

Comment: you can write the code to parse load with register first then stuff and just reuse that code for store.  Its a stretch, a really lazy programmer...at the end of the day why does it matter, it is what it is.  assembly language is tied to the assembler program, and no reason why you have to conform to any other so if you want your own mips asm language then just write your own assembler.  As to why someone or a group of someones did something in the past, is rarely going to have fact behind it and just be a gues at best, not an SO question.